# SmsMessage length calculator for iOS

Tags: ios

In Android there is a great method [`SmsMessage.calculateLength`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/gsm/SmsMessage.html#calculateLength(java.lang.CharSequence,%20boolean)) you can give a string to it and it will detect its encoding and return an array where you can find how many characters are left for 1 sms message, or how many sms messages are there in the string...

I wonder if there is such a method in iOS? Sorry if the question is too simple, I am not a iOS guy.

Comment: Since you can not send an SMS without the message composer why do you want to calculate the length. The message composer has the option to show the message length/

Comment: @rckoenes I do not want to send message as GSM SMS message, my app will use SMS gateway for it, but I still need to calculate the length of the SMS to show information to the user how much will he be charged and so on... May be you know some third party library which can do this?

Comment: Asking for a library is offtopic for Stackoverflow. But just to give you an idea, you should count the bytes of the message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The way you send a text message on iOS is by using the [`MFMessageViewController`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMessageComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html) class, which presents its own UI, kind of like an activity on Android. It also shows the length of the message for you.

As there is no way to send a text message without using this pre-built iOS component, something like what you're asking for does not exist.

Comment: May be there is a third party library to do such kind of staff. Because there are a lot of apps for international messages which have such a counter. It is not a very hard thing to do it myself, but if there will be a lib for this it will be great.

Comment: @Andranik I would expect that these apps use SMS gateways to send messages and not the device's hardware SMS/MMS sending functionality. And you're right, there probably are libraries for this, but I've never worked with any of them.